# How to put FLAT JSON values in JsonObject in Android

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am working on a project. I want to put values of flat json array in json object. Control is not going inside loop. After putting values in array list through adapter nothing is showing. How can I do this? I want to get values from all five arrays given in string and want to show in a ListView
        I worked on it but facing errors. Below is my flat json string:

```
  String[] data1 ={"[{\"messages_id\":\"1685307\",\"message\":\"\",\"message_link\":\"\",\"location\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"1005\",\"ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"created\":\"2016-05-13T10:01:07+00:00\",\"uploads\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"147\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"comment_count\":\"16\",\"share_count\":\"54\",\"video_count\":\"0\",\"feed_count\":\"0\",\"group_id_fk\":\"0\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":\"\",\"updated_by_id\":\"9227\",\"is_hidden\":\"0\",\"hidden_date\":\"\",\"is_spam\":\"0\",\"is_spam_active\":\"0\",\"spam_activate_by\":\"\",\"spam_active_date\":\"\",\"spam_hidden_date\":\"\",\"message_balance\":\"0.00000\",\"currency_id\":\"0\",\"image_or_video\":\"1\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_image\":\"0\",\"is_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"is_classified\":\"0\",\"is_classified_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_post\":\"0\",\"parent_post_id\":\"0\",\"is_vmessage_allowed\":\"1\",\"is_greatjob\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"short_desc\":\"\",\"category_id\":\"0\",\"home_sticky_pos\":\"0\",\"is_del\":\"0\",\"del_on\":\"\",\"del_by\":\"0\",\"greatjob_status\":\"0\",\"feeling_status_id\":\"0\",\"share_desc\":\"\",\"post_type\":\"0\",\"sub_post_type\":\"0\",\"posted_in_page_id\":\"0\",\"hiphiphooray\":\"\",\"donate_status\":\"0\",\"donate_count\":\"0\",\"greatjob_count\":\"1\",\"blood_type\":\"\",\"dislike_enable_disable\":\"0\",\"em_id\":\"974516853079990866772\",\"post_images\":[{\"message_image_id\":\"62502\",\"image_name\":\"ltldlddig1mfakw7rdn3\",\"cdn_public_id\":null,\"image_description\":null,\"message_id\":\"1685307\",\"width\":\"225\",\"height\":\"225\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"1463133667\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":null,\"updated_by_id\":\"0\",\"user_ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"comment_count\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"share_count\":\"0\",\"description\":null,\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_classified_images\":\"0\"}],\"feelind_data\":[],\"comments\":[{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2786469\",\"like_count\":\"2\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"7061\",\"comment\":\"nice and to nice .\",\"comment_time\":\"1463467638\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Dawood Walter\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2788590\",\"like_count\":\"1\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"2040\",\"comment\":\"dfadfsa;dltuslkjvrvet\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472009\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"xccgyfojnq3g1sux6ono\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Muhammad Rasheed\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789001\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6150\",\"comment\":\"kj;kj;lupiohjjhjhfllkytkl\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472647\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"yn4abtkqcxkc7ygz0cmr\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Kosar Perveen\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789148\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6899\",\"comment\":\"Hxixig nfxdoy cgxoxtdiohx xigtix\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472867\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"sfnu4vujqsgjd1ek121b\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abuzar Fayyaz\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2794532\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6756\",\"comment\":\" <img src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.incomeon.com\\/assets\\/front_end\\/images\\/smileys\\/two_hearts.png\\\" width=\\\"19\\\" height=\\\"19\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" style=\\\"border:0;\\\" \\/>\",\"comment_time\":\"1463484164\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"j6tzgtu869l3rgahkqo0\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abdul Hafeez\"}],\"user_data\":[{\"name\":\"Mrs Nawaz Khan\",\"id\":\"1005\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"profileimage\":\"https:\\/\\/res.cloudinary.com\\/incomeon\\/image\\/upload\\/c_fill,f_auto,h_70,pg_1,w_70\\/p46g0z2dflosj5zrzh0k\"}],\"like_status\":2,\"is_owner\":0,\"user_video_data\":\"\",\"video_pay\":0,\"message_action_budget\":\"0.00100\"}", "{\"messages_id\":\"1685307\",\"message\":\"\",\"message_link\":\"\",\"location\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"1005\",\"ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"created\":\"2016-05-13T10:01:07+00:00\",\"uploads\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"147\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"comment_count\":\"16\",\"share_count\":\"54\",\"video_count\":\"0\",\"feed_count\":\"0\",\"group_id_fk\":\"0\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":\"\",\"updated_by_id\":\"9227\",\"is_hidden\":\"0\",\"hidden_date\":\"\",\"is_spam\":\"0\",\"is_spam_active\":\"0\",\"spam_activate_by\":\"\",\"spam_active_date\":\"\",\"spam_hidden_date\":\"\",\"message_balance\":\"0.00000\",\"currency_id\":\"0\",\"image_or_video\":\"1\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_image\":\"0\",\"is_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"is_classified\":\"0\",\"is_classified_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_post\":\"0\",\"parent_post_id\":\"0\",\"is_vmessage_allowed\":\"1\",\"is_greatjob\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"short_desc\":\"\",\"category_id\":\"0\",\"home_sticky_pos\":\"0\",\"is_del\":\"0\",\"del_on\":\"\",\"del_by\":\"0\",\"greatjob_status\":\"0\",\"feeling_status_id\":\"0\",\"share_desc\":\"\",\"post_type\":\"0\",\"sub_post_type\":\"0\",\"posted_in_page_id\":\"0\",\"hiphiphooray\":\"\",\"donate_status\":\"0\",\"donate_count\":\"0\",\"greatjob_count\":\"1\",\"blood_type\":\"\",\"dislike_enable_disable\":\"0\",\"em_id\":\"974516853079990866772\",\"post_images\":[{\"message_image_id\":\"62502\",\"image_name\":\"ltldlddig1mfakw7rdn3\",\"cdn_public_id\":null,\"image_description\":null,\"message_id\":\"1685307\",\"width\":\"225\",\"height\":\"225\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"1463133667\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":null,\"updated_by_id\":\"0\",\"user_ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"comment_count\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"share_count\":\"0\",\"description\":null,\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_classified_images\":\"0\"}],\"feelind_data\":[],\"comments\":[{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2786469\",\"like_count\":\"2\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"7061\",\"comment\":\"nice and to nice .\",\"comment_time\":\"1463467638\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Dawood Walter\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2788590\",\"like_count\":\"1\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"2040\",\"comment\":\"dfadfsa;dltuslkjvrvet\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472009\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"xccgyfojnq3g1sux6ono\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Muhammad Rasheed\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789001\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6150\",\"comment\":\"kj;kj;lupiohjjhjhfllkytkl\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472647\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"yn4abtkqcxkc7ygz0cmr\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Kosar Perveen\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789148\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6899\",\"comment\":\"Hxixig nfxdoy cgxoxtdiohx xigtix\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472867\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"sfnu4vujqsgjd1ek121b\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abuzar Fayyaz\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2794532\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6756\",\"comment\":\" <img src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.incomeon.com\\/assets\\/front_end\\/images\\/smileys\\/two_hearts.png\\\" width=\\\"19\\\" height=\\\"19\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" style=\\\"border:0;\\\" \\/>\",\"comment_time\":\"1463484164\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"j6tzgtu869l3rgahkqo0\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abdul Hafeez\"}],\"user_data\":[{\"name\":\"Mrs Nawaz Khan\",\"id\":\"1005\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"profileimage\":\"https:\\/\\/res.cloudinary.com\\/incomeon\\/image\\/upload\\/c_fill,f_auto,h_70,pg_1,w_70\\/p46g0z2dflosj5zrzh0k\"}],\"like_status\":2,\"is_owner\":0,\"user_video_data\":\"\",\"video_pay\":0,\"message_action_budget\":\"0.00100\"}]"};
```

And this is my  Java code  given below

```
try {
                    Log.d("hy one ", "two");


                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(data1);
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    JSONObject jsonObject1;
                Log.d("json val", String.valueOf(jsonArray1.length()));

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("objitem"+i, jsonObject.toString());
                        Log.d("jsonobject", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

                        like = jsonObject.getString(like_count);
                        unlike = jsonObject.getString(unlike_count);
                        comment = jsonObject.getString(comment_count);
                        share = jsonObject.getString(share_count);
                        feed = jsonObject.getString(feed_count);
                        greatjob = jsonObject.getString(greatjob_count);
                        created = jsonObject.getString(created1);
                        message1 = jsonObject.getString(message);

                            Log.d("My Like Value is ", like);

                            HashMap<String, String> arr = new HashMap<>();
                            arr.put("like_count", like);
                            arr.put("unlike_count", unlike);
                            arr.put("comment_count", comment);
                            arr.put("share_count", share);
                            arr.put("feed_count", feed);
                            arr.put("greatjob_count", greatjob);
                            arr.put("name", id);
                            arr.put("created", created);
                            arr.put("message", message1);

                        Log.d("array list", String.valueOf(arr));


                            //Log.d("array", String.valueOf(arr));
                            arrayList.add(arr);
                        Log.d("array list", String.valueOf(arrayList));
                        }
                   // }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            adapter = new Dashboard_Adapter(dashboard1.this, arrayList);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in **String** in json format instead of **array**. Copy and replace this String with your array.

```
   String data1 =
              "[{\"messages_id\":\"1685307\",\"message\":\"\",\"message_link\":\"\",\"location\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"1005\",\"ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"created\":\"2016-05-13T10:01:07+00:00\",\"uploads\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"147\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"comment_count\":\"16\",\"share_count\":\"54\",\"video_count\":\"0\",\"feed_count\":\"0\",\"group_id_fk\":\"0\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":\"\",\"updated_by_id\":\"9227\",\"is_hidden\":\"0\",\"hidden_date\":\"\",\"is_spam\":\"0\",\"is_spam_active\":\"0\",\"spam_activate_by\":\"\",\"spam_active_date\":\"\",\"spam_hidden_date\":\"\",\"message_balance\":\"0.00000\",\"currency_id\":\"0\",\"image_or_video\":\"1\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_image\":\"0\",\"is_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"is_classified\":\"0\",\"is_classified_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_post\":\"0\",\"parent_post_id\":\"0\",\"is_vmessage_allowed\":\"1\",\"is_greatjob\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"short_desc\":\"\",\"category_id\":\"0\",\"home_sticky_pos\":\"0\",\"is_del\":\"0\",\"del_on\":\"\",\"del_by\":\"0\",\"greatjob_status\":\"0\",\"feeling_status_id\":\"0\",\"share_desc\":\"\",\"post_type\":\"0\",\"sub_post_type\":\"0\",\"posted_in_page_id\":\"0\",\"hiphiphooray\":\"\",\"donate_status\":\"0\",\"donate_count\":\"0\",\"greatjob_count\":\"1\",\"blood_type\":\"\",\"dislike_enable_disable\":\"0\",\"em_id\":\"974516853079990866772\",\"post_images\":[{\"message_image_id\":\"62502\",\"image_name\":\"ltldlddig1mfakw7rdn3\",\"cdn_public_id\":null,\"image_description\":null,\"message_id\":\"1685307\",\"width\":\"225\",\"height\":\"225\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"1463133667\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":null,\"updated_by_id\":\"0\",\"user_ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"comment_count\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"share_count\":\"0\",\"description\":null,\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_classified_images\":\"0\"}],\"feelind_data\":[],\"comments\":[{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2786469\",\"like_count\":\"2\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"7061\",\"comment\":\"nice and to nice .\",\"comment_time\":\"1463467638\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Dawood Walter\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2788590\",\"like_count\":\"1\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"2040\",\"comment\":\"dfadfsa;dltuslkjvrvet\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472009\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"xccgyfojnq3g1sux6ono\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Muhammad Rasheed\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789001\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6150\",\"comment\":\"kj;kj;lupiohjjhjhfllkytkl\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472647\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"yn4abtkqcxkc7ygz0cmr\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Kosar Perveen\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789148\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6899\",\"comment\":\"Hxixig nfxdoy cgxoxtdiohx xigtix\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472867\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"sfnu4vujqsgjd1ek121b\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abuzar Fayyaz\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2794532\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6756\",\"comment\":\" <img src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.incomeon.com\\/assets\\/front_end\\/images\\/smileys\\/two_hearts.png\\\" width=\\\"19\\\" height=\\\"19\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" style=\\\"border:0;\\\" \\/>\",\"comment_time\":\"1463484164\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"j6tzgtu869l3rgahkqo0\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abdul Hafeez\"}],\"user_data\":[{\"name\":\"Mrs Nawaz Khan\",\"id\":\"1005\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"profileimage\":\"https:\\/\\/res.cloudinary.com\\/incomeon\\/image\\/upload\\/c_fill,f_auto,h_70,pg_1,w_70\\/p46g0z2dflosj5zrzh0k\"}],\"like_status\":2,\"is_owner\":0,\"user_video_data\":\"\",\"video_pay\":0,\"message_action_budget\":\"0.00100\"}, {\"messages_id\":\"1685307\",\"message\":\"\",\"message_link\":\"\",\"location\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"1005\",\"ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"created\":\"2016-05-13T10:01:07+00:00\",\"uploads\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"147\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"comment_count\":\"16\",\"share_count\":\"54\",\"video_count\":\"0\",\"feed_count\":\"0\",\"group_id_fk\":\"0\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":\"\",\"updated_by_id\":\"9227\",\"is_hidden\":\"0\",\"hidden_date\":\"\",\"is_spam\":\"0\",\"is_spam_active\":\"0\",\"spam_activate_by\":\"\",\"spam_active_date\":\"\",\"spam_hidden_date\":\"\",\"message_balance\":\"0.00000\",\"currency_id\":\"0\",\"image_or_video\":\"1\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_image\":\"0\",\"is_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"is_classified\":\"0\",\"is_classified_video\":\"0\",\"is_shared_post\":\"0\",\"parent_post_id\":\"0\",\"is_vmessage_allowed\":\"1\",\"is_greatjob\":\"1\",\"title\":\"\",\"short_desc\":\"\",\"category_id\":\"0\",\"home_sticky_pos\":\"0\",\"is_del\":\"0\",\"del_on\":\"\",\"del_by\":\"0\",\"greatjob_status\":\"0\",\"feeling_status_id\":\"0\",\"share_desc\":\"\",\"post_type\":\"0\",\"sub_post_type\":\"0\",\"posted_in_page_id\":\"0\",\"hiphiphooray\":\"\",\"donate_status\":\"0\",\"donate_count\":\"0\",\"greatjob_count\":\"1\",\"blood_type\":\"\",\"dislike_enable_disable\":\"0\",\"em_id\":\"974516853079990866772\",\"post_images\":[{\"message_image_id\":\"62502\",\"image_name\":\"ltldlddig1mfakw7rdn3\",\"cdn_public_id\":null,\"image_description\":null,\"message_id\":\"1685307\",\"width\":\"225\",\"height\":\"225\",\"is_active\":\"1\",\"add_date\":\"1463133667\",\"added_by_id\":\"1005\",\"update_date\":null,\"updated_by_id\":\"0\",\"user_ip\":\"110.36.184.88\",\"comment_count\":\"0\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"unlike_count\":\"0\",\"share_count\":\"0\",\"description\":null,\"is_shared_product\":\"0\",\"shared_with\":\"1\",\"is_classified_images\":\"0\"}],\"feelind_data\":[],\"comments\":[{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2786469\",\"like_count\":\"2\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"7061\",\"comment\":\"nice and to nice .\",\"comment_time\":\"1463467638\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Dawood Walter\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2788590\",\"like_count\":\"1\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"2040\",\"comment\":\"dfadfsa;dltuslkjvrvet\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472009\",\"liked_by\":\"3608\",\"profileimage\":\"xccgyfojnq3g1sux6ono\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Muhammad Rasheed\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789001\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6150\",\"comment\":\"kj;kj;lupiohjjhjhfllkytkl\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472647\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"yn4abtkqcxkc7ygz0cmr\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Kosar Perveen\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2789148\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6899\",\"comment\":\"Hxixig nfxdoy cgxoxtdiohx xigtix\",\"comment_time\":\"1463472867\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"sfnu4vujqsgjd1ek121b\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abuzar Fayyaz\"},{\"iliked\":\"0\",\"comment_id\":\"2794532\",\"like_count\":\"0\",\"comment_image\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"6756\",\"comment\":\" <img src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.incomeon.com\\/assets\\/front_end\\/images\\/smileys\\/two_hearts.png\\\" width=\\\"19\\\" height=\\\"19\\\" alt=\\\"\\\" style=\\\"border:0;\\\" \\/>\",\"comment_time\":\"1463484164\",\"liked_by\":\"\",\"profileimage\":\"j6tzgtu869l3rgahkqo0\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"post_owner_id\":\"1005\",\"name\":\"Abdul Hafeez\"}],\"user_data\":[{\"name\":\"Mrs Nawaz Khan\",\"id\":\"1005\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"profileimage\":\"https:\\/\\/res.cloudinary.com\\/incomeon\\/image\\/upload\\/c_fill,f_auto,h_70,pg_1,w_70\\/p46g0z2dflosj5zrzh0k\"}],\"like_status\":2,\"is_owner\":0,\"user_video_data\":\"\",\"video_pay\":0,\"message_action_budget\":\"0.00100\"}]";
```

Then in java code . I can not find declaration to jsonObject variable. So I changed your jsonObject1 to jsonObject and tested.

```
      JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(data1);
      JSONArray jsonArray;
      JSONObject jsonObject;
      Log.d("json val", String.valueOf(jsonArray1.length()));

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
        jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("objitem" + i, jsonObject.toString());
        Log.d("jsonobject", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

        String comment_count = jsonObject.getString("comment_count");
        System.out.println(comment_count);
        //rest of your code 
      }
```

Comment: I want it as a second item.... and want to get all values from it and how to put all these in a single arraylist

Comment: second item? Sorry I don't understand that. Make sure your data1 string is in valid json format.

Comment: i want to get more values of objects of this string.like this JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObject.getJSONArray("post_images");
                for(int j=0;j<jsonArray2.length();j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
                    String strimg = jsonObject2.getString("image_name");
                    str = cloudinary.url().transformation(new Transformation()
                            .width(400).height(400).crop("fill").chain()
                            .width(200)).generate(strimg);  and want to add both values in single arraylist

Comment: You will get it  in the for loop if your string is in valid json array format

Comment: i am trying but not working and still getting errors .can you please send me an example